# Setting super class attributes in Django Models

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models

If I have a django model such as:

```
from django.db import models

class Super(models.Model):
    field_a = models.IntegerField()
    field_b = models.DateTimeField()
```

And another model which extends it:

```
class Sub(Super):
    pass
```

Then how to I go about setting fixed values for `field_a` and `field_b` as part of the construction of `Sub` instances?
Say, for example that I want to set `field_a` to `123` and `field_b` to `datetime.now()` as part of the `Sub` constructor.

For what it's worth, I have a Java background and basically what I'm looking for is the python/django equivalent of:

```
public class Super
{
    int fieldA;
    long fieldB;

    public Super(int a, long b)
    {
        this.fieldA = a;
        this.fieldB = b;
    }
}

public class Sub extends Super
{
    public Sub()
    {
        super(123, System.currentmillis());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd guess you'd want a [default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#default)? Applying Java ideas to Python 1:1 is not very useful, they're different languages with some very distinct philosophies.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix the Java with Python - it is not the way Python works!

- there is no **this** in Python - you should pass it to the method as first argument (and standard naming for this argument is *self*)
- there are no constructors like in Java - instead of this there is **__init__** method

The generic example for your problem is:

```
    class Sup:
        field = "default one"
        def __init__(self, value=None):
            if value != None:
                self.field = value

    class Sub(Sup):
        def __init__(self, value=None):
            if value != None:
                Sup.__init__(self, value)

    default = Sub()
    print default.field

    modified = Sub("modified one")
    print modified.field
```

you can also call **super** in inheriting class - [read more here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super)

Also please notice that your qestion has nothing common with Django - if I were you I would start with some good Python tutorial before creating a Django project